# Jquery code only ever executes the first statement

Tags: jquery

I have the below HTML code

```
<div class="testimonial closed">

    <p class="author">Author name</p>

    <p class="quote">This is a quote</p>

</div>
```

And I have the below jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

    if ($('.testimonial').hasClass('closed')) {

        $("p.author").click(function() {

            var parent = $(this).parent();
            window.console.log("Opened with author name");
            $(parent).addClass("opened").removeClass("closed");

        });

    } else if ($('.testimonial').hasClass('opened')) {

        $("p.author").click(function() {

            var parent = $(this).parent();
            window.console.log("Closed with author name");
            $(parent).addClass("closed").removeClass("opened");

        });

    }

});
```

My problem is that the second part of the code never gets executed.

I added some outputs to the console and can see that the second part of the code is never executed as I am always shown the message 'Opened with author name' regardless of how many times I click on the paragraph with the class of author.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Is it because the new class 'opened' that is applied on the first click is somehow not available in the 'else if' statement?  If not then how do I get it to recognise that the class has changed from 'closed' to 'opened'?

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you only run the code on load, so the `click()` handler for the `.opened` element is never applied. Instead, use a single `click()` handler and toggle the classes on the parent element. Try this:

```
$("p.author").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.testimonial').toggleClass("opened closed");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yyodo7ak/)

Comment: Yes agree with your answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the code to run on page load and the html always has closed as the calls. Therefore, the first statement is always true. It is never run again so will never reach the other statement. Change `<div class="testimonial closed">` to `<div class="testimonial opened">` and the other will always happen. You have to check the condition inside the click event.

I think this will get what you are looking for.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $("p.author").click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $(parent).toggleClass("opened closed");
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that you can provide multiple classes to a single `toggleClass()` call if you separate them by a space.